# How POSIX timer actually works?

Tags: c, multithreading, timer, operating-system, performance-testing

I want to synchronize 10 threads with semaphores in such a way that there is some delay between the execution of two consecutive threads. So, to provide a delay of 2 sec (in this case), I am using a timer.

```
//Import 
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 199309
#include <sched.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <syscall.h>
#define NUM_THREADS 10

#define CLOCKID CLOCK_REALTIME
#define SIG SIGUSR1
int ret;
timer_t timerid;
sem_t sem;
sem_t mute;

struct sigevent sev;
struct itimerspec its;
long long freq_nanosecs;
sigset_t mask;
struct sigaction sa;

pthread_t tid[NUM_THREADS];

static void handler(int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *uc)
{
    if(si->si_value.sival_ptr != &timerid){
        printf("Stray signal\n");
    }
    sem_post(&sem);
}

void *threadA(void *data_)
{
    int i = 0, s,n;
    int turn = (intptr_t)data_;
    int sid = syscall(SYS_gettid);
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("ipc.out","a");    
    fprintf(fp,"thread_%d %d\n",turn,sid);  
    fclose(fp); 

    while(1)
    {
        sem_wait(&sem);
        printf("Thread #-> %d\n",turn);
        sem_wait(&mute);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
        {
            /* some work */
        }
        its.it_value.tv_sec = 2;
        its.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;
        its.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
        its.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;

        ret = timer_settime(timerid, 0, &its, NULL);
        if ( ret < 0 )
            perror("timer_settime");

        sem_post(&mute);
        // Timer's code ends
    }

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int data = 0;
    int err,i;

    sem_init(&sem, 0, 1); 
    sem_init(&mute, 0, 1); 

    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sa.sa_sigaction = handler;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sigaction(SIG, &sa, NULL);

    sev.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
    sev.sigev_signo = SIG;
    sev.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &timerid;
    ret = timer_create(CLOCKID, &sev, &timerid);
    if ( ret < 0 )
        perror("timer_create");

    while(data < NUM_THREADS)
    {
        //create our threads
        err = pthread_create(&tid[data], NULL, threadA, (void *)(intptr_t)data);
        if(err != 0)
            printf("\ncan't create thread :[%s]", strerror(err));

        data++;
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

So, If thread # 1 has got the CPU then it should again get the CPU after the executions of all other threads.
But in my case, thread # 0 is coming after every thread. 
Output:

```
root@localhost:~/Desktop/C_files# ./a.out 
Thread # -> 2
Thread # -> 0
Thread # -> 3
Thread # -> 0
Thread # -> 7
Thread # -> 0
Thread # -> 4
Thread # -> 0
Thread # -> 5
Thread # -> 0
Thread # -> 8
Thread # -> 0
Thread # -> 1
Thread # -> 0
Thread # -> 6
Thread # -> 0
Thread # -> 9
Thread # -> 0
Thread # -> 2
Thread # -> 0
```

Why the thread # 0 is coming so frequently (between each thread)? I want one thread to start its 2nd execution only if all others have run once.

Comment: Wrap your sem_wait and sem_post calls with error handling. `if(sem_wait(&sem) == -1) perror("sem_wait");` I got the error as sem_wait was interrupted by a system call.

Comment: Change from SA_SIGINFO to SA_RESTART and it will work. Refer http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html , Interruption by system call part

Comment: Replacing SA_SIGINFO with SA_RESTART I can see some stray signal interrupting my signal handler.